# Why does httpd handle requests for wrong hostnames in SSL mode?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https, httpd, subdomain

I have an SSL-enabled virtual host for my sites at `example.com:10443`

```
Listen 10443
<VirtualHost _default_:10443>
  ServerName example.com:10443
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/ssl/private/sub.class1.server.ca.pem"
  SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/ssl/private/StartCom.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

Browsing to https://example.com:10443/ works as expected.
However, also browsing to https://subdomain.example.com:10443/ (with DNS set) shows me the same pages (after SSL certificate warning). I would have expected the directive `ServerName example.com:10443` to reject all connection attempts to other server names.

How can I tell the virtual host not to serve requests for URLs other than the top-level one?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to happen? What would it mean to "reject" a connection attempt? What *specifically* do you want to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not enabled `NameVirtualHost` so the `_default_` would send any connection to your server to the config.  Try it like this. I added spacing for readability

```
NameVirtualHost *:10443
Listen 10443

<VirtualHost *:10443>
  ServerName example.com:10443
  ServerAlias example.com:10443
  ServerAdmin admin@example.com

  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log"

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/private/example.com.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/ssl/private/sub.class1.server.ca.pem"
  SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/ssl/private/StartCom.pem"

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem not to use the `NameVirtualHost` option so Apache will not bother to check the hostname of the server in the request sent by the client. The request will be directed to the first `VirtualHost` section, where the IP:port matches, and that's it. Whatever hostname you use, does not matter, you'll get exactly the same website. This is called IP-based virtual host matching.

Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/details.html for the full semantics of virtual host matching, including the results of using `NameVirtualHost`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache always find the best ip:port based in the first pass, when only connection level details are available, then looks at hostnames in a 2nd pass from what remains (if in 2.2, a NameVirtualHost directive has to be present to allow the 2nd step)

*default* is the same as *.  If you've only got one virtual host for a port, it will be used regardless of whether there is a name-based vhost match.

If you want a catch-all for * or a specific IP, create it as the first virtual host in a set of matching ip:port combinations.  You can reject things from there.